# String not scanned 2nd time when using gets function

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, c-strings, gets

When I am using `gets` function to scan `item` name in the first loop it runs properly but in the 2nd loop, it skips to Quantity `quant` without scanning item name.
I also tried using `%s` previously then it is working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Dmart
{
    char item[10];
    int quant, price;
};
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct Dmart cust1[3], cust2[3];

    printf("\nFor Customer 1\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Item: ");
        gets(cust1[i].item);
        printf("Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &cust1[i].quant);
        printf("Price: ");
        scanf("%d", &cust1[i].price);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nFor Customer 2\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Item: ");
        gets(cust2[i].item);
        printf("Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &cust2[i].quant);
        printf("Price: ");
        scanf("%d", &cust2[i].price);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nBill of Customer 1\n");
    printf("Item\t\tQuantity\tPrice\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", cust1[i].item, cust1[i].quant, cust1[i].price);
    }

    printf("\nBill of Customer 1\n");
    printf("Item\t\tQuantity\tPrice\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", cust2[i].item, cust2[i].quant, cust2[i].price);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[VS Code [Terminal Output][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyKD7.png)

Comment: Side note: You may want to read this: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/12149471)

Comment: Use exclusively `fgets()` for user input. Forget `scanf()` exists.

Comment: Mixing `scanf` and `fgets` will lead to problems unless you're very careful. As mentioned by @pmg, use only `fgets` to read full lines (well, hopefully), and then you can use e.g. `sscanf` to parse the lines.

Comment: You may want to read this for alternatives to using the function `scanf`: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 1):

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. So do not use it.

The problem of the code is that after this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &cust2[i].price);
```

the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter still is in the input buffer. So the next call of `gets` reads an empty string encountering at once the new line character.

Instead you could either always use the function `fgets` and then convert the entered string to an integer for integer data members of the structure or you can use `scanf` instead of gets like for example

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("Item: ");
    scanf( " %9[^\n]", cust1[i].item);
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &cust1[i].quant);
    printf("Price: ");
    scanf("%d", &cust1[i].price);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string

```
    scanf( " %9[^\n]", cust1[i].item);
           ^^^^
```

It allows to skip white spaces in the input buffer.